# Android Layout designer doesn't open XML file created in IntelliJ

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

My main working tool is IntelliJ. So I use it to create XML files and layouts for Android activities. However, if I open such XML file in Eclipse, it does not recognize it as layout file and does not load its GUI designer (I open XML file via Eclipse Layout Editor). If I create an XML file in Eclipse, the GUI designer loads properly.

The very content of Eclipse layout XML filet and IntelliJ layout XML file is 100% identical.

What am I doing wrong?
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT: I have created new project in IntelliJ. Added some test elements into Main.xml. Exported project to Eclipse format (File->Export to Eclipse...). Closed IntelliJ, opened Eclipse, Imported the newly created project, opened Main.xml with Layout Editor and NOTHING again. This is structure of Main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
            />
    <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="just testing text"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="test inside of layout"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how Eclipse Layout Editor sees this XML file.
[image]

Comment: yes. the xml file is in that dir

Comment: I have narrowed the problem and I will open a new question! This one will be close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you copy the file to the `res/layout` folder, right click on the project in the project explorer and hit refresh to let it know Eclipse the file is there. You might need to clean the project and rebuild also.

An xml file does not depend on where you created, it's just text.

Comment: Does not work. Eclipse sees it but opens it with its XML editor.

Comment: Well, to start you don't have a closing </RelativeLayout>, so this xml is not readable

Comment: I have. This is just a part of XML file. :))

Comment: can you post the full layout?

Comment: I will add it. It's nothing complicated. Do you work in IntelliJ as well? Do you have problems with Eclipse layout editor?

Comment: It's done. Newly created test project, added some random elements, Eclipse Layout Editor does not want to open it as expected.

Comment: No, I do not work with IntelliJ but there's no reason why an xml file cannot be read as such. Can you look at it with an hex editor? Maybe there's a null character or some other odd character in it that prevents Eclipse from using the file?

Comment: BTW, won't it allow you to set up a locale, theme, etc? (The selectors right next to "Portrait")

Comment: It does allow me, I just didn't do it. I tried it before and no visual elements appear. I also do not understand what might be the problem because, as you said, XML is XML. The only thing that comes to my mind is that Eclipse adds some invisible files or attributes into XML files so maybe that where the problem is.

Comment: @Aleadam Please suggest me Answer for this . Above whole steps i did but it didnt worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Try this

1. Right click on that xml file
2. Select `Open With`
3. In that select `Android Layout Editor`

Comment: It opens it with Layout Editor, but I cannot see any graphical elements. I will edit the question and add some code.

Comment: This works for me, however this does not resolve doubleclicking on the file and having it open in the layout editor.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the name given to your xml is just all small letters and underscore, no Caps. I had the same problem and changing the Case worked well

Answer (score 0):

just give it time to generate the view.  the bigger your layout file, the longer it takes.  what you're seeing is a lack of a progress bar that shows it's doing something.  just be patient for a while and it should come up